# Sitecore Url not working - layout not found error

Tags: upgrade, redirect, urls, url-rewrite

We have just upgraded from Sitecore 8.1 update 4 to Sitecore 9.0 update 2. Almost all the functionalities are working. We have an issue with one url. When I tried to access the URL below, I got the `Layout not found` error.

http://mycompanydomain.com/customer-care-support

Here are few things I tried.

1. Opened the page in experience editor mode - Page is opening in Experience editor mode.
2. Checked weather item is published or not - It's published.
3. Opened the item in preview mode from Presentation tab > Preview - `The layout for the requested document was not found` was shown
4. Renamed the item to `customer-care-support-new`. - **New URL is working.**

I have searched for `customer-care-support` in entire solution. But didn't find anything.

Has anyone faced a similar issue or have suggestions to resolve it?

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried renaming every word in the item name, e.g. to `customer-test-support` or to `customer-care-test`? It looks like some specific setup of your app site/item/device resolvers...

Comment: @MarekMusielak I tried with the name you have suggested. The page is loading with those url.

Comment: Can you switch Sitecore desktop to `web` database and see if there is a sibling item in `web` database with same name or display name?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I had a folder called 'customer care support', deleted it and it worked. I have found out that, Sitecore 9 started adding hypen to url if it contains the space. That was causing issue after migration. Thanks for the help Genius.

Comment: Marek, you should add your comment as an answer. The hyphen/space angle is key here!

Comment: @PaRsH I converted my comments into an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may happen when you have a sibling item (e.g. folder or item without a layout) with the same name or display name.

Be aware that Sitecore replaces hyphens to spaces when it tries to find an item in the tree, so if your url is `customer-care-support` you have a sibling with a name `customer 
care support` next to your `customer-care-support` item, you can never be sure which item will be resolved.

It's very important that you never have items with the same name under one parent node - it will only cause issues, trust me.

There may be a case when you had item with the same name, you published it and then removed from `master` database, but never unpublished that item. Best always have a quick check in your `web` database if there aren't any trashed left.